# Git and GitHub for non programmers

Tags: git, cloud-service, github, google-drive, dropbox

I use git and GitHub in many projects where I collaborate with others in an academic context. For example, we produce study materials using markdown (md → html / pdf) or we analyse data in research projects using R / python. Git and GitHub is great for the following people (let's call them *beneficiaries*):

1. **Students** who want to see (and possibly change) the source code of our study materials
2. **Teachers** who want to create similar study materials for their own courses
3. **Researchers** who want to see (and possibly use) the source code for our research projects

However, these tools induce much pain on people who collaborate with me on these projects but simply won't understand this workflow (let's call them *detractors*). I've have been advocating the use of these tools for years have been forced to realize that some people *will not learn them*, period.

For the sake of the *beneficiaries*, I would like to stick to using git / GitHub. But for the sake of the *detractors*, I'm looking for a way to *drastically* simplify the workflow. What I'm looking for is a tool which:

- provides a GUI
- Always pulls before a push
- uses more familiar terms such as:

  - *select* instead of *add*
  - *save* instead of *commit*
  - *sync* instead of *push*
- Auto suggests a commit message
- ... more features to make git / GitHub more similar to Dropbox, GoogleDrive etc.

Comment: Budget range...?

Comment: I'm primarily interested to know if something like this even exists, irrespective of the price. FOSS would be preferred of course.